# Is it possible to attach more than 25MB of files to an outgoing gmail message via SMTP?

Tags: email, google-drive-api, gmail, phpmailer, attachment

Gmail allows regular browser users to "attach" files larger than 25MB in size by allowing them to first upload the file to Google Drive and then send it.

This is done seamlessly through the gmail UI, just a single extra click for the user informing them that it will be uploaded to Google drive and sent as a link instead of a regular file attachment.

Is there any way to have a paid gsuite gmail account do that automatically for you when attaching files via SMTP that are over 25mb in size?

Or will I have to do exactly as they do? Upload via a Google Drive API and then email the google drive download links?

Answer (score 0):

A free Gsuite account, accessed via the GMail UI in a browser window, automatically adds a large attachment to drive and shows the "Your file is larger than 25 MB. It will be sent as a Google Drive link.". So it seems likely that a paid Gsuite account, accessed via the GMail UI in a browser window, would do the same (however I can't test this, lacking a paid account).

However this service is part of the GMail online email client. You are obviously using a different (non-specified, probably offline) email client, and possibly one or more SMTP servers between it and the Google SMTP server.

To get what you want, you would need either the client or smtp server to recognise that the file attachments are larger than a set size, and then automatically upload the files to drive and insert the drive link.

It might be possible to find an email client that has Google Drive integration to this extent, Everdesk http://www.everdesk.com/features#google_support and EMClient http://www.emclient.com/features both claim Google integration, but I have not investigated whether they automatically upload large attachments like the online Gmail interface.

Online services such as Zapier, Sendtodocs and IFTTT won't work in this case as they rely on getting the content to them, and obviously large attachments will be blocked by the Google SMTP server.

Answer (score 0):

Good question. I did a test and sent myself such an attachment, and then did "view original" in gmail. This is what it said

```
Date: Thu, 2 Mar 2017 08:36:40 +0000
Subject: gmail drive test
To: Todo <foo@bar.com>
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=001a114a970436d05b0549bb55bd

--001a114a970436d05b0549bb55bd
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

=E2=80=8B
 Untitled spreadsheet
<https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/149LLw1nY24vlYx_d=
sWn4QWwnM/edit?usp=3Ddrive_web>
=E2=80=8B

--001a114a970436d05b0549bb55bd
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<div dir=3D"ltr">=E2=80=8B<br><div class=3D"gmail_chip gmail_drive_chip" st=
yle=3D"width:396px;height:18px;max-height:18px;background-color:#f5f5f5;pad=
ding:5px;color:#222;font-family:arial;font-style:normal;font-weight:bold;fo=
nt-size:13px;border:1px solid #ddd;line-height:1"><a href=3D"https://docs.g=
oogle.com/spreadsheets/d/149LLw1nY24vlYx_dsig/edit?=
usp=3Ddrive_web" target=3D"_blank" style=3D"display:inline-block;overflow:h=
idden;text-overflow:ellipsis;white-space:nowrap;text-decoration:none;paddin=
g:1px 0px;border:none;width:100%"><img style=3D"vertical-align: bottom; bor=
der: none;" src=3D"https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/doclist/images/icon_11_spre=
adsheet_list.png">=C2=A0<span dir=3D"ltr" style=3D"color:#15c;text-decorati=
on:none;vertical-align:bottom">Untitled spreadsheet</span></a></div>=E2=80=
=8B<br></div>

--001a114a970436d05b0549bb55bd--
```

So it looks like all you need is the weblink in a separate mime part and the GMail web client deals with it automagically.